# DRUPAL 7 meta description

Tags: drupal

Как в *DRUPAL 7* удалить *meta description*?

Подскажите где его отредактировать, или вообще удалить.

Comment: А откуда он вообще у вас появляется? Вы используете какие-то специальные модули (вроде [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag))? Просто, насколько мне известно, в базовой поставке Drupal 7 не использует этот мета-тег.

Answer (score 3):

Отключить или настроить соответствующим образом модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: На том, что meta description добавляет этот модуль. Друпал "из коробки" не устанавливает подобные метатеги.
Подскажите автору давать более точные вопросы.